# Mysql:join query with count

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, left-join

### Here is my table structure

```
  1) Posts table
    -------------
      a)id
      b)title



2) Comments table
----------------
   a)id
   b)post_id (FK POST table)
   c)is_approved 
   d)comment
```

I would like to fetch all post along with total comments that match `is_approved=true`

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
Posts table
-----------
id title
----------
1   sample1
2   sample2
3   sample3

Comments table
--------------
id post_id is_approved comment
1   1       1           hello
1   2       1           hi
```

I've tried this query

```
SELECT p.title ,COUNT(c.post_id)as total FROM posts as p 
LEFT JOIN comments as c ON p.id=c.post_id
WHERE  c.is_approved=1 GROUP BY c.post_id
```

**Expected Output**

```
 title   total
-----------------
   sample1 1
   sample2 1
   sample3  0
```

I am not getting the above result the current output is

```
title   total
    -----------------
       sample1 1
       sample2 1
```

Comment: When you do the left join, `c.isapproved` will be null or false for sample3. 

take a look at:
`SELECT* FROM posts as p 
LEFT JOIN comments as c ON p.id=c.post_id
WHERE  c.is_approved=1 GROUP BY c.post_id`

Comment: TRY THIS: 
    
    `SELECT p.title ,COUNT(c.post_id)as total FROM posts as p 
    LEFT JOIN comments as c ON p.id=c.post_id
    WHERE c.is_approved=1 OR total IS NULL
    GROUP BY c.post_id`

Comment: You have to move `c.is_approved=1` from `WHERE` to `ON`, otherwise the `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos can you give an example

Comment: `LEFT JOIN comments as c ON p.id=c.post_id AND c.is_approved=1 GROUP BY c.post_id`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos its worked:)